# VSCode Prettier adding quotes to css where I don't want them

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, salesforce, prettier

I am using VSCode's Prettier extension and trying to work on some html for a Salesforce Lightning Web Component. In my html, I have a div like so

```
<div class={someVar}</div>
```

This is the correct syntax for this, however, whenever I save Prettier adds quotes like this

```
<div class="{someVar}"
```

which causes a syntax error. I can't seem to find this setting anywhere in the prettier settings or anything online about how to disable this addition.

I have some other html files that this doesn't happen to when I save, just this new html file I just added.

Comment: post your .prettierrc file?

Comment: I don't have one for this workspace

Comment: Hm, what exactly have you done, what's installed? Have you seen https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/prettier/ ?